# Is it necessary to use "it" as an object? - Yes, I know it but... / Yes, I know it

Tags: pronouns

Is it necessary to use "it" in such answers, or is it redundant? Could you explain why?

> Yes, I know **it** but I still love her.
>
> Yes, I know **it**.

I guess "it" might be used for emphasis, so it's not redundant but also not obligatory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think "for emphasis" means in your cited context, but I do think you're probably mistaken. The normal way of expressing emphasis here would be to place heavy stress on the word ***know*** (or much more rarely, in certain specific contexts, placing heavy stress on the conjunction ***but***). If any kind of determiner ***was*** included in your examples, it would more likely be ***that*** rather than ***it*** - where it *can* be perfectly idiomatic to place the stress as *Yes, I know **that**, but [blah blah]*. Mostly we don't use ***it*** in such contexts, though.

Comment: Looking at this again, I'm intrigued to realise that I have no idea why it's perfectly natural to place heavy stress on the "demonstrative determiner" in *Yes, I know **that**, but [caveat]* (and indeed the *personal* pronoun in *Yes, I know **him**, but not his wife*), but it seems to be impossible to idiomatically stress whatever kind of pronoun it is in *Yes, I know **it**, but [caveat]*. I might raise this point on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions) to see if anyone there can explain this "lop-sidedness" in acceptable usage.

Comment: If anyone's interested, I ***did*** ask: [Why is emphatic "Yes, I know THAT" okay, but not "Yes, I know IT"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583740/why-is-emphatic-yes-i-know-that-okay-but-not-yes-i-know-it?noredirect=1#comment1458937_583740)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three possibilities:

- You may omit the object: "Yes, I know, but I still love her." This is common.
- You may use "it": "Yes, I know it, but I still love her." This does not add any emphasis. It also sounds a bit unusual, because we would not usually use the pronoun "it" here.
- You may use "that": "Yes, I know that, but I still love her." This is common and (as FF said in a comment) allows a speaker to place stress on "that" in order to emphasize that word.

The second clause can, of course, be omitted in the above sentences.

Your other example ("Yes it is, but it’s getting warmer.") concerns a different issue because you are talking about including or removing an entire clause ("it is"). If you want to ask about that sentence, then I'd recommend writing a new question.

Answer (score 0):

One could say either "I know" or "I know that" -- both are acceptable in casual conversation; the latter would be preferred in a less-informal context -- but  "I know it" doesn't work.

"I know that" is an elided version of "I know that piece of information." *That* is a determiner, whereas *it* is a pronoun; correctly identifying parts of speech is important because they function differently.

The example you gave ("I know it") doesn't work because there's no antecedent for the pronoun *it* -- no earlier stated noun that *it* stands in place of. (An example of *it* standing in for a previously stated noun: "Last night I saw the  new *Hulk* movie, and I loved it.")

Because I'm not an academic (I'm a very good grammarian and a longtime copy editor), I can't tell you why it's OK to say "I know" rather than "I know that," but I can tell you that such an omission is not uncommon in American English. For ex., if asked the question "Have you completed your homework?", an American would reply, "I have" whereas a British person would reply, "I have done." Both omit an object ("I have done it"), but the British response omits less than the American one does.